# Sql Dateadd is affecting Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to add hours and seconds to an existing datetime field to create a new field.
The hours and seconds are coming in fine, but the year is being altered as well, which is undesirable. 
Heres what I'm Using:

```
,Dateadd(hh,SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.PMF_RFQTime / 3600,SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.PMF_RFQRECEIVEDDATE)+DateAdd(n,SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.PMF_RFQTime%3600 / 60,SALESQUOTATIONTABLE.PMF_RFQTime)  as newdate
```

The caluculations are in there to convert seconds from midnight to a time (i know, i didnt make that decision)

So if i start with a time of 31428, it calculates out to 8:43.
Now, when I do the add from date 2014-03-25 00:00:00.000 it gives me 2100-04-11 08:43:00.000 which is the correct hour and minute, but the year, month and day have been altered.

Comment: take your time part into a variable and date part into a variable then concatenate both the variables

Comment: @developer oh please don't do that

Comment: Methinks you may be overcomplicating this problem.

Comment: Is it what you want? select DateAdd(mi,43,DateAdd(hh,8,'2014-03-25 00:00:00.000'))

Comment: Right, you should be nesting DATEADD, not adding them. Or just saying `DATEADD(MINUTE, 31428/60, column)`.